# To Remove only specified parent element not child element in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Input xml like below.

```
<part type="frontmatter">
<section level="1"><title>THIEME Atlas of Anatomy</title>
........
</section>
<section level="1">
<title></title><para><emph type="bold">To access additional material
......
</section>
</part>
<part type="content">
<section level="1">
<title id="p001">Structure and Development of Organ Systems</title>
...
<section level="2">
<title>Suggested Readings</title>
.......
</section>
</section>
</part>
```

Output should be

```
<part type="frontmatter">
<section level="1"><title>THIEME Atlas of Anatomy</title>
........
</section>
<section level="1">
<title></title><para><emph type="bold">To access additional material
......
</section>
</part>
<part type="content">
<title id="p001">Structure and Development of Organ Systems</title>
...
<section level="2">
<title>Suggested Readings</title>
........
</section>
</part>
```

My xslt is:

```
<xsl:template match="section[position()=1]"><!-\-//-\->
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::part[@type='content'][not(title)]">
        <part type="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </part>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to remove `<section level="1">` element which is appearing under `<part type="content">` where "title" element should not appear between these two elements. If "title" is appear under part element then should not make any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `section` element, under a `part` element, where there is no preceding `title`, then the template match should look like this

```
<xsl:template match="part[@type='content']/section[@level='1'][not(preceding-sibling::title)]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="part[@type='content']/section[@level='1'][not(preceding-sibling::title)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, in this particular example, you may be able to simplify it to this

```
<xsl:template match="part[@type='content']/section[1]">
```

So, just remove the `section` element if it is the first child element of `part`. This would not work if you could have elements other that `title` preceding the `section`.

Comment: Thanku for you response Tim C. Below code is worked properly.

<xsl:template match="part[@type='content']/section[@level='1'][not(preceding-sibling::title)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>